# How do we know 3 is a divisor?

Tags: self-learning

The following is a supposedly true claim, and I came across it in the Coursera course [Introduction to Mathematical Thinking](https://www.coursera.org/learn/mathematical-thinking) (Assignment 7/7) as part of an explanation by the instructor to the proof why $\sqrt{3}$ was irrational. The line that perplexes me goes like this:

> If 3 divides the square of some x ∈ ℕ without a remainder, then 3
>   also divides x without a remainder.

How do we know that this is true for all squared natural numbers?

Comment: It follows from the fact that $3$ is prime

Comment: "If 3 divides the square of any $x\in \Bbb N$ without a remainder": this is poorly written, it should be *some* $x$.

Comment: Every number can be written in one of the forms $3n,3n+1,3n+2$.  Just look at what happens if you square each type

Comment: This question was voted down to -1 when I came across it. This looks like a perfectly fine question to me; please don't vote it down without leaving an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $x$ is not a multiple of 3, then either $x=3k+1$ or $x=3k+2$

For $x= 3k+1$, we get $x^2 = 9k^2+6k+1 = 3(3k^2+2k)+1$

For $x= 3k+2$, we get $x^2 = 9k^2+12k+4 = 3(3k^2+2k+1)+1$

As you notice, in either case $x^2$ is not a multiple of $3$

Thus is $x^2$ is a multiple of $3$, then $x$ must be a multiple $3$

Answer (score 4):

It does not hold only for squared natural numbers. It simply results from this more general result:

> *Euclid's lemma*: If a prime $p$ divides a product of natural numbers, it divides at least one of the factors.

As in the present case there's only a repeated factor…

Comment: Thank you, I am reading about it, but need some time to understand it. Can I just ask you if lemmas are something that mathematicians learn by heart at the beginning, or one is actually supposed to understand their proofs?

Comment: A lemma , usually, is a preparatory results  which is used in the proof of another result. Some lemmas are actually fundamental results for their domain, such as Euclid's lemma in arithmetic. A generalisation is known a Gauß' lemma, which asserts that if a number $n$ (not necessarily prime) divides a product $xy$, and $n$ is coprime to $x$, then $nˆdivides the other factor.